# RangeValidation Throws error

Tags: html, asp.net

I am using a range validation in asp for a date range...

```
  <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatordtmStartDateEdit" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Start Date is required" ControlToValidate="dtmStartDateEdit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidatordtmStartDateEdit" runat="server" Type="String" ErrorMessage="Range is +/- 1 year" ControlToValidate="dtmStartDateEdit" MaximumValue="DATETIME.Today.ADDYEARS(1).ToShortDateString()" MinimumValue="DATETIME.Today.ADDYEARS(-1).ToShortDateString()"></asp:RangeValidator>
                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderStartDateEdit" runat="server" TargetControlID="dtmStartDateEdit"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                <asp:TextBox ID="dtmStartDateEdit" runat="server">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
```

The error I get is that the Maximum cannot be smaller than the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Add `type` attribute , and  I wonder `ToShortDateString()` returns String or use `Type = Date` if not.

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidatordtmCloseDateAdd" runat="server"
ErrorMessage="Range is +/- 1 year" ControlToValidate="dtmCloseDateAdd" 
MaximumValue="DATETIME.Today.ADDYEARS(1).ToShortDateString()" 
MinimumValue="DATETIME.Today.ADDYEARS(-1).ToShortDateString()" 
Type = "String">
</asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: The field I am doing the validation on is a text box. Changing it does not work...<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatordtmStartDateEdit" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Start Date is required" ControlToValidate="dtmStartDateEdit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidatordtmStartDateEdit" runat="server" Type="String" ErrorMessage="Range is +/- 1 year" ControlToValidate="dtmStartDateEdit" MaximumValue="DATETIME.Today.ADDYEARS(1).ToShortDateString()" MinimumValue="DATETIME.Today.ADDYEARS(-1).ToShortDateString()">

Answer (score 0):

What I did was extract the Max and Min statements and placed them in the PageLoad event for each RangeValidator. It works fine.